# Getting Location Name from Longitude and Latitude in BingMap

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am a WP7 developer. I have longitude and latitude of a location. Is there anyway to get the info the location defined by the coordinate ie longitude and latitude.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via the [Bing Maps REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701722.aspx), you need to perform a [reverse geocode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx). This is done by GET-ing the following request:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey
```

Which will return the address in XML format:

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <Copyright>
    Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.
  </Copyright>
  <BrandLogoUri>
    http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
  </BrandLogoUri>
  <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
  <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
  <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
  <TraceId>
    dd31ffaf098f4406b7ecdd0da36680ff
  </TraceId>
  <ResourceSets>
    <ResourceSet>
      <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
      <Resources>
        <Location>
          <Name>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</Name>
          <Point>
            <Latitude>47.640568390488625</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-122.1293731033802</Longitude>
          </Point>
          <BoundingBox>
            <SouthLatitude>47.636705672917948</SouthLatitude>
            <WestLongitude>-122.137016420622</WestLongitude>
            <NorthLatitude>47.6444311080593</NorthLatitude>
            <EastLongitude>-122.1217297861384</EastLongitude>
          </BoundingBox>
          <EntityType>Address</EntityType>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine>1 Microsoft Way</AddressLine>
            <AdminDistrict>WA</AdminDistrict>
            <AdminDistrict2>King Co.</AdminDistrict2>
            <CountryRegion>United States</CountryRegion>
            <FormattedAddress>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</FormattedAddress>
            <Locality>Redmond</Locality>
            <PostalCode>98052</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Confidence>Medium</Confidence>
          <MatchCode>Good</MatchCode>
          <GeocodePoint>
            <Latitude>47.640568390488625</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-122.1293731033802</Longitude>
            <CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod>
            <UsageType>Display</UsageType>
            <UsageType>Route</UsageType>
          </GeocodePoint>
        </Location>
      </Resources>
    </ResourceSet>
  </ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

Comment: i need the info in Json so can anyone suggest me a way to convert xml to json....

Comment: The data is also available in JSON format if you change `o=xml` to `o=json` in the request URL

Comment: Don't forget, you will need a Bing Maps API key - go to http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ to get one

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a web service provided by Microsoft that returns the city, state and country based on the latitude and longitude you provide.

Create a web service reference in your project by providing the link http://msrmaps.com/TerraService2.asmx

I have named the service as myTerraService

```
myTerraService.TerraServiceSoapClient client = new myTerraService.TerraServiceSoapClient();
        client.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted += new EventHandler<myTerraService.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompletedEventArgs>(client_ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted);
        client.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceAsync(new myTerraService.LonLatPt { Lat = latitude, Lon = longitude });
    }

    void client_ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted(object sender, myTerraService.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string location = e.Result; // this string will have city, state, country
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://www.dizzey.com/development/net/getting-started-windows-phone-7-getting-location-reverse-geocoding-weather/