# Microsoft API for GPS based mobile phones

Tags: c#, wpf, gps

I have to write an application in C#. The purpose of this application will be to get the location of gps based devices (probably mobile phones).

I want to ask that which Microsoft API i have to use and will that API will get location of any gps based mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you need correctly, then I suggest you make use of the GeoCoordinateWatcher class that is in the System.Device.Location assembly. This will make use of the phones GPS to give you the latitude and longitude of the phones current location.

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
                watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
                {
                    MovementThreshold = 20
                };

                watcher.PositionChanged += this.watcher_PositionChanged;
                watcher.Start();

private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender,   GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        if (!e.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
        {
            longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
            latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        }
}
```

Comment: once you've got the latitude and longitude you can make use of them to get the location details like city name, state, country etc. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109996/getting-location-name-from-longitude-and-latitude-in-bingmapThis link will help you.

Comment: Thanks, and i want to confirm that is there any need to write any code on my GPS phone for ths? and what would be the input to the above code? My Phone's GPS Identifier or something like that? And if yes then how can i come to know about my Phone's GPS Identifier?

Comment: Switch on your phone GPS. It should be able to receive the signal. You can use the above code to determine the latitude and longitude. The link above will guide you in determining the city, state, country from the lat-lon.

Comment: how this works ? any basics of this Code? will you please let me know ? and how can it detect my phone? i want to confirm about authentication ? Would be there some authentication to track my Phone?

Comment: One thing more i want to ask here is that is this code i have to write at the Mobile Phone? Actually i want to write WPF code that will track my GPS phone without writing any Application code at the Mobile Phone.

Comment: Yes the code i've mentioned is whats to be written on the mobile phone. I'm not sure as to how the wpf app is to integrate with the phone.