# Location details from GeoCoordinates in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Address name of GPS coordinate with wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294474/how-to-get-address-name-of-gps-coordinate-with-wp7)

I am developoing a WP8 application.In my application i want to get the details of a particular location like location name from its geocoordinates. I can get the device current gps position . But it gives only the geocoordinates. Is there any service which gives location details from geocoordinates. Please help me.

Comment: [How to get Address name of GPS coordinate with wp7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294474/how-to-get-address-name-of-gps-coordinate-with-wp7)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The previous question was targeted at WP7, WP8 provides a new and improved way of doing reverse geocode lookups. See @JustinAngels answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the bing API to get specific location details.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701722.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109996/getting-location-name-from-longitude-and-latitude-in-bingmap

Hope thsi helps.

Kelvin

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is called reverse geocoding. Converting a Geocoordinate to an address.

As was mentioned before you can use Google and Bing on WP7 to achieve that. On windows phone 8 Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding are supporteded as part of the framework. You can read an overview to GeoCoding [at this Nokia intro article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Maps) (under "Geocoding") and a more comprehensive overview [at this other Nokia article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html;#toc_Searchingforanaddress).

Here's an example of reverse Geocoding converting from a coordinate to an address:

```
private void Maps_ReverseGeoCoding(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery()
    {
        GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(37.7951799798757, -122.393819969147)
    };
    query.QueryCompleted += query_QueryCompleted;
    query.QueryAsync();
}

void query_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Ferry Building Geocoding results...");
    foreach (var item in e.Result)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(item.GeoCoordinate.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Name);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Description);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingFloor);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingName);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingRoom);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingZone);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.City);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Continent);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Country);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.CountryCode);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.County);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.District);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.HouseNumber);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Neighborhood);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.PostalCode);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Province);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.State);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.StateCode);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Street);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Township);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

When I run this code snippet on my WP8 I get the following messagebox:

[image: MEssageBox showing details for the ferry building]

Comment: I am getting exceptions `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` and `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` on the statement `query.QueryAsync();`. What can be the possible cause of this ?

Comment: @Mayank Check if your app is making multiple calls, only one call at a time can be made, hope its helpful